# how to exclude a specific folder from the gradle build?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I want to commit files located in a specific folder to the git repository. On the other hands, I don't want to build this specific folder when it builds. How can I do this?

When I build it on the jenkins, I got this error like the following. I have to exclude the folder where it located in 'grunt' directory.

```
fatal: cannot create directory at 'grunt/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/latest-version/node_modules/package-json/node_modules/registry-url/node_modules/npmconf/node_modules/config-chain/node_modules/proto-list': Filename too long

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1407)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$8.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1586)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: I don't think this is a git question. You've got the git part nailed, but your build related question is outside of the git domain. Try adding language specific tags e.g. Node.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I will change the tag of this. Maybe It will relate with the tag, jenkins-plugin.